# What is the difference between invoking a perl script via sh or perl

Tags: shell-script, perl

I have a simple Hello World perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print 'Hello world.';
```

It works fine if I run it via `perl <file_name>`, but it fails I run it via `sh <file_name>`.

My understanding of the first line is that it invokes the perl shell (similar to #!/usr/bin/bash will invoke a bash shell). So what exeactly is the difference between the two commands?

I found this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1133334 that states `sh <file_name>`  "In that case, you don't run Perl at all, but the shell, which will call the program 'print'." IF that's the case is the #! just being interpreted as a comment. If so, is it needed at all?

(I am aware that I can chmod +x the file and run it dirrectly, but I just want to know the difference between the two methods I was using)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you execute a file directly

```
/path/to/script/filename
```

The shebang line will be searched for the interpreter to run it. If you run `perl` or `sh` with an argument, they'll behave as documented: try to interpret the file as a script in Perl or shell, respectively.

When you explicitly set the interpreter from the command line (such as `sh foo.pl` or `perl foo.pl`), the shebang line is not used to determine the interpreter to run. It *is* parsed for possible options, (for example with a `#!/usr/bin/perl -w` shebang, running the script as `perl foo.pl` will enable the `-w` flag) but it is not used to determine which program should interpret the script.

So, running a perl script as `sh foo.pl` means your system will try to interpret it as an `sh` script instead, despite the perl shebang line.

Comment: @terdon: Not completely correct with your update. perl _will_ parse the shebang line in a script for switches.

Comment: @Dubu even when that script is launched as `sh foo.pl`? Perl won't even be _called_ in that case, how will it parse the shebang? The shebang is only read if you don't specify an interpreter (`sh` or `perl` or whatever) when launching the script. That's the problem that the OP is facing. It will indeed be parsed if you launch with the correct interpreter (`perl foo.pl`) but not if you use the wrong one (`sh foo.pl`).

Comment: @terdon: The Answer now says that the shebang line will be ignored when the script is called as an argument to `perl` _or_ `sh`. I wanted to point out that this does not hold when called as `perl <filename>`.

Comment: @Dubu fair enough. Clearer now?

Comment: @terdon Almost perfect. Whether the shebang line is interpreted depends on the interpreter, of course. `perl` does it, for `sh` I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

So you haven't made the script executable? sh isn't going to automatically assume that things with those file extensions are executable, so you either need to run `perl <file name>` or you need to make it executable with `chmod +x`

Answer (score 0):

The two may not be the same depending on how Perl is installed on the system you're using. Try entering this command:

`which perl`

It will show you the path to the executable file called "perl" in your `$PATH` (type `echo $PATH` to see your `$PATH`). On many systems, this will be `/usr/bin/perl`, which is where Perl is usually installed - this is why the "shebang" line at the start of most Perl scripts also assumes it is there.

On some systems, though, the path to `perl` may be different. In that case, you may get a different result typing `perl your_script.pl` versus using the shell to interpret the shebang line, e.g. `./your_script.pl`; in the former case, the `perl` interpreter in your `$PATH` will interpret your script, while in the latter case, the one at `/usr/bin/perl` will. These may not be the same.

In many cases, `perl` is your own installation of Perl, probably newer than the one that came with the system (in `/usr/bin`). In other words, there is more than one Perl interpreter on the system. In that case, you had better figure out which one you want and hardcode its path in your shebang line so that your script is not accidentally interpreted with the wrong version of Perl. (You can also write things like `use 5.12;` in your script for additional safety in this regard.) To check the version of the Perl interpreter, enter `/path/to/perl -v`.